# How to detect clickable label position inside listview xamarin forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to do something like this

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKR38.png)

I have `Listview` with clicked `label` " Edit " I want when i click this label it's position is detected and display

label at Aliaddress is clicked

I Used `TapGestureRecognizer` for this but when i google it i fount that selected item doesn't work with TapGesture

This is my **xaml**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserAdresses}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAddress}" HorizontalOptions="{Binding HoriRLLR}" RowHeight="{Binding RowHeight}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Country}"  TextColor="Orange" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>

                                            <Label Text="{Binding Address}"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"></Label>

                                            <Label Text="{Binding City}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"></Label>

                                            <Label Text="{translator:Translate Edit}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium">

                                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EditAddressesCommand,  Source={x:Reference CustomerAdressesPage}}"/>
                                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <Label.Effects>
                                                    <controls:UnderlineEffect></controls:UnderlineEffect>
                                                </Label.Effects>

                                            </Label>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

my **code**

```
 public DelegateCommand EditAddressesCommand => new DelegateCommand(EditAddresses); 
        public DelegateCommand DeleteAddressesCommand => new DelegateCommand(DeleteAddresses);
        private readonly IPageDialogService _dialogService;

        private ObservableCollection<CustomerAdressesModel> _userAdresses;
        public ObservableCollection<CustomerAdressesModel> UserAdresses
        {
            get { return _userAdresses; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _userAdresses, value);
            }
        }


        private CustomerAdressesModel _selectedAddress;
        public CustomerAdressesModel SelectedAddress
        {
            get { return _selectedAddress; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedAddress, value); }
        }


        private void EditAddresses()
        {
            _dialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Test", "Edit Clicked", "Ok");
        }
```

How can i do this and detect the position of clicked label

Comment: use CommandParameter to bind the current object "."

Comment: "." related to my model or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this: `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` inside `TapGestureRecognizer`

Xaml:

```
 <Label.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer
           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
           Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EditAddressesCommand,  Source={x:Reference CustomerAdressesPage}}"/>
 </Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

ViewModel:

```
 public ICommand EditAddressesCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<YourModel>((YourModel model) =>
            {
                //Access your model properties
            });
        }
    }
```

Hope this may solve your problem.